# How to bold a string within a JS object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const paymentOptionsRadio = [
{
    key: 'fullamount',
    value: `Full amount - ${getCurrency(bookingData?.currencyIsoCode)} ${
        bookingData?.expectedPayments[0].amount
    }`,
},
];

    <ListRadioButtons
        name='paymentType'
        value={selectedPaymentOptionType}
        values={paymentOptionsRadio}
        onChange={handlePaymentChange}
        defaultValue={selectedPaymentOptionType}
    />
```

How to bold a string within a JS object? I am using react.

My attempt:

```
const paymentOptionsRadio = [
        {
            key: 'fullamount',
            value: `Full amount - ${(
                <b>{getCurrency(bookingData?.currencyIsoCode)}</b>
            )} ${(<b>{bookingData?.expectedPayments[0].amount}</b>)}`,
        },
    ];
```

[image]

Why mark this question down? I have provided examples, my attempt, screenshot...

Comment: If your attempt, by placing `<b>` tags in the output, didn't work, then it's likely that the content is created in such a way that HTML is stripped from it. I'd suggest you target the content using CSS instead. You probably should also fix the `[object Object]` issue in the output too.

Comment: I only need to bold the payment amount though, so would still need a span or something to target with css?

Comment: Is your file .jsx?

Comment: yes it is .tsx :)

Comment: @PriyenMehta Don't do that, questions should be self contained not having required content on external sites.

Comment: value: `Full amount - ${getCurrency(bookingData?.currencyIsoCode)} ${bookingData?.expectedPayments[0].amount}`, 

There is no containing element that splits the full amount text and payment amounts :(

Comment: You dont "bold something in a javascript object" - you bold something when you output it to some UI. Show us your UI code, and we can help how to bold that string.

Comment: Ok one sec jamie

Comment: I added my MUI component that takes in the object

Comment: Still not much use, we need to know what `ListRadioButtons` does

Comment: I'm just passing the value down into that component into another component, it creates a radio. Don't worry though, I don't think this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach you are trying does not work because react automatically prevents html injection, in order to do that you need to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` in your `ListRadioButtons` component

```
// ListRadioButtons
<label
    htmlFor="html"
    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: value }}
></label>
```

or to turn the entire value into a jsx element, example:

```
const paymentOptionsRadio = [
{
    key: 'fullamount',
    value: <span>Full amount - <b>{getCurrency(bookingData?.currencyIsoCode)}</b> <b>{bookingData?.expectedPayments[0].amount}</b></span>,
},
];
```

If you are not able to use a jsx element for the `value` have a look at this similar question and see if the answers are of any use to you
[Highlight text using ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29652862/highlight-text-using-reactjs)

Answer (score -1):

```js
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const get = () => {
    return "30";
  };
  const paymentOptionsRadio = `Full amount - <b>${get()}</b> `;

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="radio" id="html" name="fav_language" value="HTML" />
      <label
        htmlFor="html"
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: paymentOptionsRadio }}
      ></label>
    </div>
  );
}
```

you can try using **dangerouslySetInnerHTML** attribute inside label tag of radio button to render html content