# How to render HTML tags from text in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, jsx

I'm working on a text highlighting and I was able to detect selection etc. Now I have something like

```
Te<span>x</span>t
```

in a string and

```
["Te", "<span>", "x", "</span>", "t"]
```

In an array. How can I render this using react in a safe way? DangerouslysetinnerHTML doesn't work here by the way (maybe needs a hook or something, but it's unsafe so, better to use something else).

*The amount of these spans can change so there may be a lot of tags.

Edit: My algorithm makes a mask (an array full of zeros) for a text and whenever user selects something it adds 1 to certain fields in array (like an interval). Then it parses the text and the mask, and when for example 01 occurs then it pastes the opening tag in between (and when 10 => closing tag). What's maybe other way of achieving Medium-like highlighting feature?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why would you want to render unsafe HTML? Is it safer to know what word/character(s) to highlight, and simply highlight them in-place? Or can you show us what you've tried at the very least?

Comment: How are you generating that array of strings? Would it be possible to change it to containe JSX elements? i.e. `["Te", <span>x</span>, "t"]` ?

Comment: possibly: [Highlight text using ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29652862/highlight-text-using-reactjs)

Comment: @Terry I just wanted to get highlighting tool perfect for my usage, so I tried to make one. I need to highlight, on certain action focus on certain highlight, and load the data to/from DB.

Comment: @amer my own algorithm that sticks <span> before selection and </span> after it.

Comment: @IVOBOT can you update post so that includes that algorithm or simplified version of it, my guess is that the modification can be made there so that you can render it without `dangereouslySetInnerHTML`

Answer (score 3):

The `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is dangerous when you try to render user content with it. What I mean, it's not more dangerous to render string with `<spans>` injected than the original string. If you want to sanitize the string, you could do it before highlighting.

`<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: "Te<span>x</span>t" }} />`

Comment: What do you mean by "sanitize"?

Comment: Sanitization basically means removing potentially harmful things from html. There are tons of libraries and APIs that do that. https://wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_sanitization