# How to highlight a piece of text like browser does?

Tags: javascript, html

I have searched the Internet and found related topics discussed:

- [Highlight text using ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29652862/highlight-text-using-reactjs)
- [How to highlight text using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644428/how-to-highlight-text-using-javascript)
- etc

But none of them can match and highlight `cd` this case:

```
<b>abc<b>def
```

But Chrome (I believe also other browsers) can do this. Try search for `cd` with your browser: **abc**def. How can we implement this function?

Comment: You could use `window.find('cd')`.

Comment: @Unmitigated It works! Can I use it locally? Combination with `getSelection` should work in most case, though.

Comment: What do you mean by locally?

Comment: Note that `window.find()` is [non-standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/find) and should not be used in production sites.

Comment: @Unmitigated Sorry for the confusion. Suppose I have an element and I need to limit the search range to this element.